# Jenkins pipeline: scp tries to copy to other remote, Host key verification failed

Tags: ssh, scp, jenkins

I use Jenkins in ubuntu server. In this case, I want to copy a file to another remote server. I use SCP command inside sshagent the Jenkins pipeline.

I tried the solution from [unable to scp in jenkins](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/284173/unable-to-scp-in-jenkins), 
already created user: jenkins, save the public key to the ubuntu@remoteip allowed_host, and it's ssh private key is saved in Jenkins credentials with the ID `jenkins-ssh-to-ubuntu`.

I also tried from the ssh directly from jenkins server to remote ip with the from the `jenkins` user in jenkins server, it can connect to the remoteip.

Whenever I want to do `scp` command in pipeline the console returns error. But when it's just usual ssh command like `cat atext.txt` it prints out the result. Here's the console log of the pipeline

```
[Pipeline] sh
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@remoteip cat atext.txt
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts).
{
  example: "it prints out the long text to the jenkins console output"
}
[Pipeline] sh
+ scp -r docker-compose-prod.yml ubuntu@remoteip:.
Host key verification failed.
lost connection
```

here's my pipeline

```
    stage('Copy requiredfile to deployment'){
        sshagent(['jenkins-ssh-to-ubuntu']){
            sh "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@remoteip atext.txt"
            sh "scp -r docker-compose-prod.yml ubuntu@remoteip:."
        }
    }
```

How can I resolve this?

**Update:** [host key verification failed when I use scp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379495/host-key-verification-failed-when-i-use-scp) question is the same as mine, but I didn't have the same console log there was no `REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!` warning

Checking the permission in the jenkins machine `stat ~jenkins/.ssh` it's 0700

```
  File: /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fc01h/64513d    Inode: 265912      Links: 2
Access: (0700/drwx------)  Uid: (  111/ jenkins)   Gid: (  115/ jenkins)
Access: 2019-01-18 03:22:46.519541657 +0000
Modify: 2019-01-18 03:07:42.447547320 +0000
Change: 2019-01-18 03:07:42.447547320 +0000
 Birth: -
```

I updated the example too, I think there's some command that works and that isn't.

**Update:** Running ssh manually using `jenkins` user

```
jenkins@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu$ ssh ubuntu@remoteip
The authenticity of host 'remoteip (remoteip)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:fingerprint.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts).
Enter passphrase for key '/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa':
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-141-generic x86_64)
```

after that welcome message, I logged in as ubuntu in remoteip machine

this is the result of `ls -la /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh`

```
jenkins@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-sgp1-01:/home/ubuntu$ ls -la /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh
total 24
drwx------  2 jenkins jenkins 4096 Jan 18 03:07 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 jenkins jenkins 4096 Jan 18 10:06 ..
-rw-------  1 jenkins jenkins 1766 Jan 18 03:07 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins  416 Jan 18 03:07 id_rsa.pub
-rw-------  1 root    root     666 Jan  7 09:40 known_hosts
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins  888 Dec 27 01:47 known_hosts.old
```

and this is the content of `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`

```
# This is the ssh client system-wide configuration file.  See
# ssh_config(5) for more information.  This file provides defaults for
# users, and the values can be changed in per-user configuration files
# or on the command line.

# Configuration data is parsed as follows:
#  1. command line options
#  2. user-specific file
#  3. system-wide file
# Any configuration value is only changed the first time it is set.
# Thus, host-specific definitions should be at the beginning of the
# configuration file, and defaults at the end.

# Site-wide defaults for some commonly used options.  For a comprehensive
# list of available options, their meanings and defaults, please see the
# ssh_config(5) man page.

Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   ForwardX11Trusted yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
#   Port 22
#   Protocol 2
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
```

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro the error is the same, but I didn't receive a message about `REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!`

Comment: What happens when you manually login as user `jenkins` and run `ssh ubuntu@remoteip` without using `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no`? Does it ask any question about adding the host key? Or does it work without questions?

Comment: @Bodo it ask to continue the connection with a warning that `The authenticity of host can't be established. ECDSA key fingerprint is ..` but it can continue connecting with the jenkins passphrase.

Comment: Is there an option to confirm that the host is the correct one? I normally get this when I connet to a new host for the first time. After confirmation the host key is saved and it will never ask again unless the host key has changed. Please run the command `ssh ubuntu@remoteip` and copy the complete output to a code block in your question. (You can anonymize the fingerprint and IP address.) Also show the output of `ls -la ~/.ssh` as user jenkins and the contents of `~/.ssh/config` and `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` if they exist.

Comment: @Bodo I already updated the question. The option was to continue the connection to the host if I'm correct.

Comment: The problem is `Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts).` As this fails it will ask the same question again the next time. So we have to find out why it fails. That's why I already asked you to also show the output of `ls -la /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh`. It would be easier to help if you already had provided all information I asked for in my previous comment.

Comment: @Bodo I'm sorry, I forget to add that previously, it is updated now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your manual command `ssh ubuntu@remoteip` cannot save the host identification as shown with

```
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts).
```

because this file is owned by `root` and not writable for user `jenkins`

```
-rw-------  1 root    root     666 Jan  7 09:40 known_hosts
```

First run as `root`

```
chown jenkins.jenkins /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts
```

then run as `jenkins`

```
ssh ubuntu@remoteip
```

The first time it should save the host identification and the next time it should not ask again. After this your `scp` command should work.